# how to create menu in statusbar in qt like PC start menu

Tags: c++, qt, statusbar

In my qt application, i have designed status bar with few icons. On the left of my status bar i have added menu icon (QPixmap) when i click that icon i need to show a menu similar to PC start menu. I searched a lot but i did not found Qwidget for this.

This is my qt application window

As per my recent comment i added my edited code below since i cannot add the code in comment section, plz suggest a solution

```
//Menu Button
    menuBtn->setIcon(QPixmap(":/new/prefix1/ic_menu_black.png"));
    statusBar()->addWidget(menuBtn);
    connect(menuBtn,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(showPopupMenu()));

void MainWindow::showPopupMenu(){


    QMenu qMenuStart;

    QAction qCmdStart1(QString::fromUtf8("Product Details"), &qMenuStart);
    qMenuStart.addAction(&qCmdStart1);

    QAction qCmdStart2(QString::fromUtf8("Memory Status"), &qMenuStart);
    qMenuStart.addAction(&qCmdStart2);

    QObject::connect(&qCmdStart1, &QAction::triggered,[](bool){
        qDebug() << "Product Details triggered"; }
    );
    QObject::connect(&qCmdStart2, &QAction::triggered,[](bool){
        qDebug() << "Memory Status triggered"; }
    );

    qMenuStart.exec();

    menuBtn->setMenu(&qMenuStart);

    qMenuStart.show();
    qMenuStart.popup(mapToGlobal(pos() - QPoint(0, qMenuStart.height())));

    qDebug()<<"Menu Clicked!";

}
```

popup menu on click of menu button

[image]

Comment: After looking into my own sources how we place context menus (e.g. in a `QTreeView`) I saw two things I consider as worth to mention: The menu is opened using [`QMenu::popup()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#popup) which accepts a position. The other thing is [`QWidget::mapToGlobal()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mapToGlobal) which is useful. If the menu should open above the button this has to be considered appropriately (e.g. by subtracting the height of the menu from the mapped-to-global y position of the label/button).

Comment: I'm not sure about the `qMenuStart.exec()`. I'm afraid this will open the menu before it is assigned to the `menuBtn` and, thus, any positioning will not be considered. Why don't you make the `QMenu` a member of `MainWindow` and configure it once (together with the `menuBtn` and `statusBar`). In this case, the `qMenuStart.exec()` becomes obsolete.

Comment: I believe, I know why you inserted the `qMenuStart.exec();`. You probably was wondering that the menu doesn't show on `qMenuStart.popup()`. Actually, it does but it is destroyed immediately afterwards (on return from `MainWindow::showPopupMenu()`) as it is a local instance. (My first guess was a crash but meanwhile I believe Qt is able to manage it.) However, the solution is still like suggested in my previous comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took your sample code and changed it to illustrate what I described in my latest comments:

Add a member variable to the `MainWindow` declaration:

```
QMenu *menuStart;
```

The changed sample code:

```
// configure start menu:
menuStart = new QMenu(menuBtn);
menuStart->addAction(QString::fromUtf8("Product Details"),
  [](bool){
    qDebug() << "Product Details triggered"; }
  );
menuStart->addAction(QString::fromUtf8("Memory Status"),
  [](bool){
    qDebug() << "Memory Status triggered"; }
  );
//Menu Button
menuBtn->setIcon(QPixmap(":/new/prefix1/ic_menu_black.png"));
menuBtn->setMenu(menuStart);
statusBar()->addWidget(menuBtn);
connect(menuBtn,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(showPopupMenu()));
```

Note:

I set `menuBtn` as parent of the `menuStart`. Thus, `menuBtn` should manage the destruction of `menuStart` when it is destroyed itself.

The signal handler becomes shorter respectively:

```
void MainWindow::showPopupMenu()
{
  menuStart->show(); // <-- trick to force layout of the menu before height() is called
  // position menu relative to menuBtn at popup
  menuStart->popup(
    mapToGlobal(menuBtn->pos() - QPoint(0, menuStart->height())));

  qDebug()<<"Menu Clicked!";
}
```

I did it carefully but couldn't test it (as it's no MCVE). So, please, take this with a "grain of salt".

Note:

I just realized that you use the "pre-Qt5" style of connecting signal handlers. Qt5 introduced a nice [extension to its signals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) supporting function pointers as well as method pointers. Due to this, I was able to do the signal handlers simply as [lambdas](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). (The lambdas are these `[](bool){/*...*/}` I connected to the action slots. I was always suspicious about these new lambdas until I realized that they are an excellent tool to write very simple adapters for signal handlers as well as to make quite compact sample code.)

Update about Lambdas:

The brackets `[]` can be used to add variables to the *environment* (or context) of the lambda. If it is empty (as I used it) only global variables and functions can be used. Using `[this]` means the current `this` pointer is added to the environment. Thus, the lambda may access member variables of the current class instance.

When I recognized lambdas the first time, I saw often `[=]` meaning the lambda gets the current context of the calling function (e.g. copies of every local function variable). I personally consider this as dangerous, especially for signal handlers. I will elaborate this a little bit:

The environment of a lambda allows to access "variables from outside" in the lambda body. Variables may be added by value or by reference. If a variable is provided by reference, it may be accessed in the lambda body but it will not grant that the life-time of the "outside" variable is long enough. (If it is not it results in a "dangling reference" with the same *Undefined Behavior* like a dangling pointer.) Does it help to prevent references at all? No. It is fine for primitive types (e.g. `int` or `float`) but could be inefficient (or even semantically wrong) for objects. Using pointer to objects instead, is as dangerous as using references. Thus, the enviroment of a lambda should be used with *care*.

As a rule of thumb, I personally use the following method to implement lambdas: I always start with an empty environment (`[]`). If I recognize a variable which I need in the lambda I add it to the environment whereby I consider its sufficient lifetime (or look for an alternative).

Update:

As I'm a personal fan of [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), I prepared a (similar) menu icon as SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="32" height="32">
  <title>Start Menu</title>
  <desc>Start Menu</desc>
  <rect id="line"
    x="4" y="6" width="24" height="4"
    style="stroke:none;fill:#444"/>
  <use xlink:href="#line" transform="translate(0,8)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#line" transform="translate(0,16)"/>
 </svg>
```

You may save this in a text file `ic_menu_black.svg` and try to load it in your app.

Qt's importer has unfortunately only limited support of SVG. Thus, not every trick which is possible in SVG will work correctly in Qt. Therefore, I modified a copy of an icon out of our Qt application to be sure that *this* will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution is perfect as i expected

Comment: Same Qt Application worked fine in windows 10,But when we run the same Qt Application in Linux(Embedded Device) compiled by arm compiler. After successful compilation, QPixmap image alone not showing and threw the following error,
'QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap' plz suggest

Comment: @DurgaSekar The loading of image files (for `QIcon`, `QPixMap`, etc.) is done by plug-ins (e.g. `qjpeg.dll` for JPEG). May be, the resp. plug-in is missing on the Linux(Embedded Device). Btw. wondering why I didn't find a `qpng.dll` (although it _did_ work in my 1st sample) I found [Qt Image Formats](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimageformats-index.html). Thus, some loaders seem to be "baked-in". I.e. converting the file to png (and changing the file name resp.) should make you independent of plug-ins.

Comment: I guess it's unnecessary to mention that Windows has DLLs, but Linux has SOs instead. Thus, the plug-in on Linux should probably be named `qjpeg.so` or something similar. (I looked into the `/lib/qt5/plugins/imageformats` of my cygwin (the most Linux like I have at hand): there is a `cygqjpeg.dll`. Thus, the plug-in names may vary a little bit between platforms...)

Comment: I searched inside ../plugins/imageformats folder, it has only 3 .so files(libqico.so,  libqsvg.so,  libqtga.so). Did not found any files related to png. i am looking for respective SO file.

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming you're trying to load a JPEG. Looking into history, I realized that you just used PNG. Thus, you may try ICO or TGA (or even SVG. SVG is a vector format.) GIMP is probably capable to convert to ICO or TGA.

Comment: Don't know why I missed the `menuBtn->setIcon(QPixmap(":/new/prefix1/ic_menu_black.png"));`. (May be, because I'm doing this beside of my professional work...) Are you sure that the path can be resolved correctly (on Linux)? Btw. I did an update with an SVG version of the menu icon.

Comment: As you said I tried svg image format and now Image displayed successfully in Linux Embedded Device, Thanks a lot for your help. Also found that libpng.so is required to display png imageformat

Comment: Regarding your previous suggestions, On click of sub menu(Product Details) qDebug is used to display text, Now i need to call a function on click of sub menu.  'menuStart->addAction(QString::fromUtf8("Product Details"),[](bool){
        productdetails();
        qDebug() << "Product Details triggered";
       });'   When i call productdetails(), i am getting following error, " 'this' was not captured for this lambda function
         productdetails();
                        ^"

Comment: @DurgaSekar I added some notes about lambdas and realized that they can become somehow tricky. Why don't you use the pre-Qt5 signal handlers until you have some practical experiences with the lambdas? You could also change the function signature of `productdetails()` and use it directly (instead of the lambda). You also may write a dedicated signal handler (with matching function signature) which calls `productdetails()` (i.e. a wrapper function).

Comment: @DurgaSekar The resp. lambda should be: `[this](bool) { this->productdetails(); }`. I was thinking twice to provide this "ready-to-use". I believe: If you use lambdas you should know what you do. (But, actually, this is true for the most features of C++...)

Comment: Thanks your both solution(signal handler and lambda) worked fine

Comment: I have to call a method from linux compiled object file 'sands_lib.o' and 'path.h' from mainwindow.cpp file, We dont know how to add these files properly and where to add and how to link and call from cpp file, we posted our question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44651753/how-to-refer-external-object-file-o-file-from-qt-on-linux
we didnot get proper idea to do this..we need your help please suggest me

Answer (score 2):

Reading your question, I was not quite sure what your actual problem is. Unfortunately, due to the security policy of our company, `i.stack.imgur.com` is blocked and I'm just in the office. Probably, your snapshot had clarified the things for me. (I could have a look at it when I'm home again.)

However, out of curiosity, I tried my luck and want to show what I've got:

Actually, it is quite easy to add a widget to a status bar using [`QStatusBar::insertPermanentWidget()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstatusbar.html#insertPermanentWidget).

Unfortunately, permanent widgets are placed on the right. If the requirement (to place it at left) is essential, this can be tweaked by nesting two status bars into each other. (Actually, every other layout should be capable also but the `QMainWindow::setStatusBar()` requires a `QStatusBar*`.)

The inner status bar is the one which has to be used for temporary messages. To prevent the funny effect of duplicated size grips, the size grip is disabled for the inner status bar (using [`QStatusBar::setSizeGripEnabled()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstatusbar.html#sizeGripEnabled-prop)).

Another side effect of nested status bars is the visualization of separators at the left and right of the inner status bar. I considered this as not that bad (concerning the aesthetical aspect) and didn't care about it.

May be, I could have used simply a [`QLabel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html) (instead of the inner status bar) for message display (losing the additional capabilities provided by `QStatusBar` e.g. the timeout for auto-clear of a message).

To provide the start button, I originally used a [`QPushButton`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html). Remembering that I have to place the start menu somehow I replaced it with a [`QToolBar`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html) as it may contain a [`QAction`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html) which in turn is ready equipped to manage a sub-menu.

As I got this working I realized the indicator which appeared at the start button when I set the menu. To keep the sample as short as possible I decided to live with this for now.

After having some communication with the questioner, I added an alternative implementation using a class derived from [`QLabel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html). The menu placement has to be done on its own. But finally, it's not that complicated...

The 2<sup>nd</sup> version is activated if `USE_LABEL` is defined (near beginning of source code).

My sample `testQStartBtn.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

#define USE_LABEL

#ifdef USE_LABEL
class StartButton: public QLabel {

  private:
    QMenu *_pQMenu;

  public:
    StartButton(QWidget *pQParent = 0): QLabel(pQParent), _pQMenu(nullptr) { }

    QMenu* menu() { return _pQMenu; }
    QMenu* setMenu(QMenu *pQMenu) { std::swap(_pQMenu, pQMenu); return pQMenu; }

  protected:
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *pQEvent);
};

void StartButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *pQEvent)
{
  if (_pQMenu && pQEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
    if (!_pQMenu->isVisible()) {
      _pQMenu->show(); // a trick to force computation of height() before
      _pQMenu->popup(mapToGlobal(pos()) - QPoint(0, _pQMenu->height()));
    } else _pQMenu->hide();
  }
}
#endif // USE_LABEL

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version: " << QT_VERSION_STR;
  // main application
#undef qApp // undef macro qApp out of the way
  QApplication qApp(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QMainWindow qWin;
  QLabel qLblCentral(QString::fromUtf8("Central\nWidget"));
  qLblCentral.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
  qWin.setCentralWidget(&qLblCentral);
  QStatusBar qStBarLayout;
  // the "Windows Start Menu" alike
#ifdef USE_LABEL
  StartButton qBtnStart;
  qBtnStart.setPixmap(QPixmap(
    QApplication::applicationDirPath() + QString::fromLatin1("/Start.png")));
#else // (not) USE_LABEL
  QToolBar qToolbarStart;
  QIcon qIcnStart(
    QApplication::applicationDirPath() + QString::fromLatin1("/Start.png"));
  QAction qCmdStart(qIcnStart, QString::fromUtf8("Start"), &qToolbarStart);
#endif // USE_LABEL
  QMenu qMenuStart;
  QAction qCmdStart1(QString::fromUtf8("Command 1"), &qMenuStart);
  qMenuStart.addAction(&qCmdStart1);
  QAction qCmdStart2(QString::fromUtf8("Command 2"), &qMenuStart);
  qMenuStart.addAction(&qCmdStart2);
  QAction qCmdStart3(QString::fromUtf8("Command 3"), &qMenuStart);
  qMenuStart.addAction(&qCmdStart3);
#ifdef USE_LABEL
  qBtnStart.setMenu(&qMenuStart);
  qStBarLayout.insertPermanentWidget(0, &qBtnStart);
#else // (not) USE_LABEL
  qCmdStart.setMenu(&qMenuStart);
  qToolbarStart.addAction(&qCmdStart);
  qStBarLayout.insertPermanentWidget(0, &qToolbarStart);
#endif // USE_LABEL
  // the rest of status bar
  QStatusBar qStBar;
  qStBar.showMessage(QString::fromUtf8("<- Start Menu"), 3000 /* ms */);
  qStBar.setSizeGripEnabled(false);
  qStBarLayout.insertPermanentWidget(1, &qStBar, 1);
  qWin.setStatusBar(&qStBarLayout);
  qWin.show();
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qCmdStart1, &QAction::triggered,
    [](bool){ qDebug() << "Command 1 triggered"; });
  QObject::connect(&qCmdStart2, &QAction::triggered,
    [](bool){ qDebug() << "Command 2 triggered"; });
  QObject::connect(&qCmdStart3, &QAction::triggered,
    [](bool){ qDebug() << "Command 3 triggered"; });
  // run application
  return qApp.exec();
}
```

I compiled with VS2013 and Qt5.6 on Windows 10 (64 bit). This is how it looks:

[image: Snapshot of testQStartBtn on Windows 10]

The updated version with the derived `QLabel` looks like this:

[image: Snapshot of updated testQStartBtn on Windows 10]

Comment: solution is fine but actually what i need to implement is click event on the left corner icon in status bar. i have created startmenu icon in status bar through Qpixmap in qlabel. 

`//Menu Icon
        menuIcon->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/new/prefix1/ic_menu_black.png"));
        menuIcon->setScaledContents(false);
        statusBar()->addWidget(menuIcon);
`
Is there any possibilities to add click action on this menuIcon(Qlabel)

Comment: I believe, it should be possible: 1. Make a derived class of `QLabel`. 2. Overload at least `mousePressEvent()`. In this case, you have to `show()` the menu in the overloaded method and probably to compute and set its correct position. I'm not quite sure whether something additional is necessary so that the `QLabel` accepts mouse events. I believe - not.

Comment: Therefore, my first intention was the usage of a `QPushButton` instead. This provides a ready-to-use signal `clicked`. So, no overloading is needed. The look of the button might be tweaked modifying its properties/style if necessary. However, the placement and show of menu in clicked signal handler has to be done nevertheless. In general: If I'm in doubt I search on `woboq.com` how it is done in Qt originally but it's a little bit tedious sometimes.

Comment: I updated the answer according to our communication.

Comment: I tried as per your solution, now my problem is on click of menu button(QPushButton) popup menu is displayed at the top left corner of the screen but not near the menu button, i attached GUI window screenshot plz refer that and suggest a solution,

Comment: @DurgaSekar Your signal handler `MainWindow::showPopupMenu()` uses `pos()` and, thus, returns the position of the main window. Please, replace it by `menuBtn->pos()`. Then it should work as expected.

Comment: @DurgaSekar Did you notice the `if (!_pQMenu->isVisible())` trick? I did this to hide the menu again if the "Start Button" is clicked the 2nd time without choosing a menu item. I considered it pretty to do it like Windows.