# QTableWidget real screen size

Tags: c++, qt

I work with A QTableWidget in my app. To calculate the max. Columns to show I need to get the real width of the QTableWidget. I tried different ways:

this (QTableWidget)

```
this->geometry()->width() = Will always report 640.
this->horizontalHeader()->length() = Will always report 1660 here in case of the amount of columns.
```

But the QTableWidget has a size of exact 1000 pixel. This confuse me.

My first Idea wa, ok you ask the app at the wrong position about the size.
SO I also asked after the MDIChild was build.

```
    QVBoxLayout * dlgSplitter = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    QHBoxLayout * topNav = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    QWidget * wdgSplitter = new QWidget(this);

    QLabel *labelTopNav = new QLabel(this);
    labelTopNav->setText(tr("This is a header"));
    topNav->addWidget(labelTopNav);
    topNav->setContentsMargins(1,8,1,0);

    dlgSplitter->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
    dlgSplitter->setSpacing(0);
    dlgSplitter->setMargin(0);

    dlgSplitter->addLayout(topNav);

    scanBoard = new QScanBoard(200, 83); //This ist he "this->" control from above

    //scrollArea->setWidget(scanBoard);
    dlgSplitter->addWidget(scanBoard);


    wdgSplitter->setLayout(dlgSplitter);
    this->setCentralWidget(wdgSplitter);

    int nWidth = scanBoard->geometry().width();
    qDebug("Breite: %d ",nWidth);
```

But this also throws the same data as the class itself do.

Do anybody know a way to read the size of the QTableWidget without its contents, just its frame?

Comment: In your code sample, what is `this`?

Comment: Sorry, QTableWidget

Comment: 640 sounds like the default width which is reported before the actual size calculation has been done. Once, I wrote a sample for menus and realized that I didn't get proper widget geometry until I called `show()`. (FYI: [SO: how to create menu in statusbar in qt like PC start menu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44451423/7478597) - the relevant part is the `StartButton::mousePressEvent()`.)

Comment: To process the real size, you could consider to derive a class from `QTableWidget` and override the `resizeEvent()`. I remember that we once realized an issue with `resizeEvent()`: The new size could be obtained from widget (calling `width()`) or from the `QResizeEvent*` passed to the `resizeEvent()`. Only one of them was correct. Unfortunately, I forgot which one. Just to keep it in mind...

Comment: Something else which just popped into my mind: `QTableWidget` is derived from [`QAbstractScrollArea`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html). The latter is a composed widget - it contains a `viewport` as well as horizontal and vertical scroll bars. The `viewport()` provides the actual client area. Hence, `viewport()->width()` might provide the better value than `width()`. (The viewport is mentioned in the [More...](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#details) description.)